# Can salted passwords be reversed?

Tags: security, salt

I have just pressed 'forgot password' on hosting24.com, only to have my password emailed to me in plain text (see image below). I contacted their technical support to question this and they have told me:

> We are using Salt encryption on our website, passwords are not stored
>   in plain text. Please let us know if you have any concerns regarding
>   the security of your data.

The way I understand it, is that once a password is 'salted' it cannot be reversed back to plain text. I am also very concerned, considering their partner company 000webhosting was victim of a [massive hacking incident recently](http://www.zdnet.com/article/000webhost-hacked-13-million-customers-exposed/), which exposed that their security was sub-par.

Thanks.

[image]

**EDIT**:
After a few heated emails I finally got this response:

> Our passwords are encrypted with a secure encryption method in the
>   database. Although we do have a decryption method in place (that is
>   used to prevent fraud), all this is going to change as we are
>   re-designing the project and updating the code to adhere to new age
>   standards. We are sorry to have let you down on this one.
>
> Please contact us with any additional questions. Happy holidays!

'New age'. Amazing.

**EDIT:**
I sent the website this link to prove a point, so I anticipate a load of down votes from their tech support.

Comment: I would be concerned if a security professional used the term "salt encryption" around me...

Comment: ***They are lying to you.***  I find it's best to assume that every website/service/etc. is insecure and to use different random passwords for each one, managed by a password management tool.

Comment: @David Thanks. I have gone in and removed all of my personal details and requested that my account to be shut down and deleted – for what it's worth.

Comment: @mylogon: Wise move.  Honestly, I wish there was some effective place to report clear and blatant indications of personal data violations like this.  (I also wish there was a way to report to users' employers, and/or those employers' clients, when Stack Overflow users openly exhibit the same thing.)

Comment: I have been schooled... 'We store passwords in salted hash format. You can find more information about this here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)'

Comment: @mylogon: Regardless of what any customer service agent ever tells you, it all comes down to one simple rule that doesn't require much cryptography knowledge to remember... If *they* can recover your password, *someone else* can too.  If the information was stored securely, *nobody* would be able to recover the plain password.  Not an attacker, not the DBA, not the owner of the company, *nobody*.

Comment: @David I've updated this to now show their response. It basically shows that the support guy was talking complete nonsense - as suspected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Salted *hashed passwords* are not directly reversible—that's the point of hashing. However one can always try to recover them through brute force, trying all possible/likely passwords to see if the hash matches.

How expensive that is to do depends on the strength of the hash used, but you would never build a system that stores and decrypts passwords that way. If they said they were storing only salted hashes, and still were able to send you the password you originally set yourself, they're clearly lying.

They don't mention hashing though:

> We are using Salt encryption on our website, passwords are not stored in plain text.

“Salt encryption” isn't a thing, but let's be as generous here as we can.

It is possible they mean they're using reversible encryption with some randomised element (variable IV, or extra data in the encrypted message) which would ensure two passwords don't get matching encrypted versions (ie the same purpose as the ‘salt’ in a hashing operation).

It's also conceivable that there could be some valid reason why they need reversible passwords, for example if they need to use the passwords to authenticate to another separate system. It's possible to build reasonable systems with reversible passwords, but compared to Good Old Bcrypt it's a whole lot more effort to manage this way (eg keys on the application server; wide-ranging internal policies to manage that; HSMs; and watertight code auditing).

Let's say we accept that this is what they've done and they've implemented it solidly (which is highly doubtful—much more likely they've got plaintext passwords or a hacked-up and vulnerable AES). Even then, they've then blown it by *sending* you the reversed password in a mail over the unencrypted public SMTP infrastructure.

There are things you can do to mitigate the untrustworthiness of the mail channel, such as sending a single-use token or temporary password that requires a new password to be set afterwards. But there is never a good reason to send an existing password, that will continue to work on the target site and which you might have used to secure other services. User-set passwords should *never* touch SMTP.

Answer (score 4):

No, they can't without astronomical computing power. I'd bet large sums of money that they have a second database of plaintext passwords.

Comment: And translated into English this answer says: find another hosting provider with a clue, that does not store plaintext passwords, and the only option they offer is to reset your password, so that you can choose a new one.

Comment: while this answer did ostensibly match the question when you answered it, it does not match the question as it currently sits.  the company admitted to using reversible encryption, not salted hashes.